# 二次元データを一次元配列で扱う際のインデックスの計算方法

Tags: javascript, array

一次元配列を二次元配列に見立てて扱うためには横幅×行位置＋列位置だと言われましたがよくわからないです。
以下コードです。

```
var SIDE_CELLS = 5;//横幅
var COLUMN_CELLS = 3;//縦幅
var ci = new Array(SIDE_CELLS * COLUMN_CELLS);
var row = '';
for(var z=0;z<ci.length;++z){
  ci[z]=z+1;
  row = row + (ci[z]<10 ? '  ' : ' ') + ci[z];
}
console.log(row);
for(var y=0;y<COLUMN_CELLS;++y){
  row = '';
  for(var x=0;x<SIDE_CELLS;++x){
    var z = y*SIDE_CELLS+x;
    row = row + (ci[z]<10 ? '  ' : ' ') + ci[z];
  }
  console.log(row);
}
```

このコード `var z = y*SIDE_CELLS+x;`　が二次元配列らしいのですが
私は頭が弱いのでよくわかりません
図のようにして考えてみようとおもってもイメージがまったく掴めません
もう２日も考えているのですがどうか助けてください。

Answer (score 2):

`var z = y*SIDE_CELLS+x;` はインデックス（添字）ですね。

３×５の配列

```
[
  [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],//row:0, ０行目１列めの内容は２（０始まり）
  [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],//row:1, １行目２列めの内容は８
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] //row:2
]
```

を一次元の配列にすると

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 ]のように単なる並びになりますが
```

そのインデックス(添字)は
添字： `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10,11,12,13,14` 
内容：`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`
列の数５でくくると
添字： `{0,1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9},{10,11,12,13,14}`

それぞれは「先頭の数＋{0,1,2,3,4}」になっていることがわかります。
それぞれのくくりの先頭の数は、
行の添字×列数（つまり０×５，１×５，２×５：０から始まる５(列の数)の倍数）になっていて
{0,1,2,3,4}は列の添字になっていることがわかります。
なので、
`２次の配列[行の添字][列の添字]` は `１次の配列[行の添字×列数+列の添字]`
（つまり２次の配列[１][２]は、１次の配列[１×５+２]と同じ(８を指す)）
の関係があることがわかります。